# how to upload file zip through restful api in jmeter

Tags: java, select, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, jmeter

EDIT: how to upload file zip through restful api in jmeter**strong text**

I have upload Zip file but result show failure message

```
{"result":"failure","message":"File not found"}
i have used Mime type:application/octet-stream
but I have run through **fiddler** it show 
{"result":"success","message":"File saved successfully"}
```

please can any one find the sloutions for it
what can do for jmeter 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any Parameter name in your HTTP Request. Put a parameter name in your Request.

The Parameter name must be carefully specified. Otherwise, your file will be going nowhere.  In order to determine the correct value do one of the following:

> Inspect page source and get “name” attribute of “file” type input.
>   Or let JMeter do it for you via the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder.

Reference: [Performance testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter).

You may also find these useful:

- [Handling File Upload in JMeter](http://artoftesting.com/performanceTesting/fileUploadInJMeter.html)
- [Testing advanced REST API File Uploads JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-advanced-rest-api-file-uploads-jmeter)

Comment: I Is resolved  just change implementation : Java client 3. Thanks